# Runtime Error на удаленной среде при абсурдных обстоятельствах

Tags: python, python-3.x

На Timus.org решал задачи, код отсылал на компиляцию Python3.8 x64 и в 1 тривиальной задаче постоянно ловил Runtime Error на 10 тесте. Заключил основное тело программы в try: <...>
except ZeroDivisionError: print(0)(чтобы заменить runtime error на wrong answer и заключая разные куски кода, найти проблемный) и стал ловить Runtime error на 8 тесте.
Как заключение кода в try: <...> except ZeroDivisionError: print(0) , где <...> заведомо рабочий код(проходит тесты 8 и 9) может вызывать Runtime error, там где раньше он исправно работал

```
#Получаем простое число по его порядковому номеру где порядок числа 2 == 0
smpllst=[2,3,5,7,11]
def simpleNum(a):
    global smpllst
    if a>len(smpllst):
        for i in range(len(smpllst),a):
            nmbr=smpllst[len(smpllst)-1]+1
            smpl=False
            while not smpl:
                nmbr+=1
                smpl=True
                for u in smpllst:
                    if (nmbr%u)==0: 
                        smpl=False
                        break
            smpllst+=[nmbr]
    return smpllst[a]
#Убираем еденички из списка 
def rmv1(lst):
    i=0
    while i<len(lst):
        if lst[i]==1:
            lst.pop(i)
        else:
            i+=1

#считываем длину последовательности перестановок(1строка),считываем в rdr саму последовательность 
longitude=int(input())
rdr2=tuple(map(int,input().split()))
rdr=[]
for i in range(longitude): rdr+=[rdr2[i]]
#в combine записываем длину всех изолированных перестановок 
cmbn=[]
for i in range(len(rdr)):
    if rdr[i]!=0:
        lp=1
        pntr=rdr[i]
        while i!=pntr-1:
            lp+=1
            tmp=rdr[pntr-1]
            rdr[pntr-1]=0
            pntr=tmp
        cmbn+=[lp]
#Ищем наименьший общий делитель для всех малый перестановок;пишем его в rslt
rmv1(cmbn)
rslt=1
q=0
while len(cmbn)>0:
    dvsr=simpleNum(q)
    have1=False
#Техномагия: c try except runtime error на 8 тесте,без них на 10
#Пытаюсь превратить runtime error в wrong answer    
    try:    
        for i in cmbn:
            if (i % dvsr)==0:
                have1=True
                break
        if have1:
            rslt=rslt*dvsr
            for i in range(len(cmbn)):
                if (cmbn[i]%dvsr)==0 : cmbn[i]=cmbn[i]//dvsr
            rmv1(cmbn)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print(-1)
    else:
        q+=1
#выводим степень перестановки(сколько раз её нужно применять на саму себя, чтобы получить исходную последовательность)
print(rslt)
```

Timus.org задача 1024(школьная)

Comment: Предлагаете угадывать вашу проблему без кода? :) Добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (кнопка [edit])

Comment: Ну вы же не знаете, как там тесты запускаются. Может вы как-то ломаете им тест )

Comment: кода 50 строк и минимизировать не получится, так как иначе  он не будет писать правильный ответ и сервер выдаст WrongAnswer на 1 тесте

Comment: `smpllst+=nmbr` - это как понимать? `list += int`?

Comment: smpllst+=nmbr в Python3.8 эта конструкция работает как добавление элемента к списку(когда тестил процедуру отдельно проблем не было) , но на всякий случай добавил[](и еще 2раза послал с [] результат не изменился)

Answer (score 0):

Я проверил вашу программу на таком входе:

> ```
> 41
> 2 1 5 3 4 10 6 7 8 9 17 11 12 13 14 15 16 28 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 41 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
> ```

Результат:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "original.py", line 49, in <module>
>     dvsr=simpleNum(q)
>   File "original.py", line 17, in simpleNum
>     return smpllst[a]
> IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

Ситуацию можно улучшить такой правкой:

```
< if a>len(smpllst):
<     for i in range(len(smpllst),a):
--------
> if a>=len(smpllst):
>     for i in range(len(smpllst),a+1):
```

P.S. Вычисление [НОК](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5) не требует разложения числа на простые множители. Через НОД проще:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    return a if b == 0 else gcd(b, a % b)


def lcm(seq):
    lcm = 1
    for v in seq:
        lcm = lcm * v // gcd(lcm, v)
    return lcm
```

В Питоне 3.9 есть встроенная функция [math.lcm](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.lcm), но у вас предыдущий Питон.

Длины циклов будет проще считать если перестановку из диапазона `[1, N]` перевести в `[0, N-1]`.

Всё вместе:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    return a if b == 0 else gcd(b, a % b)


def lcm(seq):
    lcm = 1
    for v in seq:
        lcm = lcm * v // gcd(lcm, v)
    return lcm


def loops(p):
    f = [False] * len(p)
    for i in range(len(p)):
        if not f[i]:
            c = 0
            while not f[i]:
                c += 1
                f[i] = True
                i = p[i]
            yield c


input()
p = [int(w) - 1 for w in input().split()]
print(lcm(loops(p)))
```